# Syntax warning in PyCharm when loading Django models through apps.get_model

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Very minor thing here but wondering if anyone has ever encountered this. There are many instances where we have models from two apps that call each other, which causes circular dependency in Django (and python). The way around this to make use of `apps.get_model`.

When I write a line that get's the model, I like to store the result in an upper case camel case format that mimics what the model would actually look like via a regular import, for example, like this: `MyModel`.

Let's have this line: `MyModel = apps.get_model('my_app', 'MyModel')`

This causes a yellow warning underline of the first `MyModel` in the line and says: **Variable in function should be lowercase**.

Is there a good way around this? Should I be naming the variable differently?

Comment: This is a pep8 compliance warning. You cannot declare variable name like `MyModel`.  PyCharm takes this type of assignment as variable assignment. Why do need to get models like this? If for foreign key  or many to many relations, you can do better by defining lazy relations like this. `models.ForeignKey('my_app.MyModel')`

Comment: In a calculated field, sometimes we need to load things from another model that are not explicitly connected by key (maybe they need to be filtered by another dimension like year and month as well, for example).

Comment: You can move this declaration to module level. PyCharm wont complain. And I think it is legal according to pep8. Should I elaborate module level?

Comment: You can add an exception for this in File/Settings/Editor/Inspections - Python/PEP 8 naming convention violation. Add `MyModel` to Ignored errors.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar I'll give that a try, thanks

Comment: @quamrana I'll go there if need be. I hate seeing the errors lol